# Change WinForm to Win Control, Works Fine but Invisible in Visual Studio Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I've converted a Windows Form into a Windows Control (by changing the code's parent from Form to Control, removing a few minor/irrelevant Form property assignments, and changing the project settings to "Class Library" instead of Windows Form Application).  The Control works great in my application, but when I open it up in Visual Studio Designer there is nothing there except the labels for the items it isn't showing me (panel1, button1, etc.).

How do I get designer working again?  It gives no errors.

Comment: @HansPassant, I see no existing references anywhere in my code to TopLevel or DesignMode.  Are you saying I need to add a DesignMode property and set it to true?

Comment: Ignore that, I read it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get the wrong designer when you do this.  The default designer for the Control class is not a DocumentDesigner, the kind of designer that supports editing nested controls.  The simplest fix is to change the base class of your class from Control to UserControl.

Comment: You are awesome!!!  What an easy fix!  I didn't know about UserControl.  Thanks for saving me from continued confusion.